# Phonegap Android App- Secure data traffic

Tags: php, javascript, security, cordova

My PhoneGap android app recuires a user login and it needs to show the user certain information after it has logged in. (App retreives XML from the PHP server, by using AJAX)

I've searched on many blogs/forums and many stackoverflow posts, trying to come up with the best security options/features.
I want to implement the following security options.

- Secure traffic by using HTTPS (http +ssl)
- [server side] User agent checks.
- Do CRC checks on the phonegap JS file and send the result along with the information request. Then make the server compare the CRC result with the result it should be. (So if someone decompiled the App, changed code, and compiled it again... we would know)
- The app can only REQUEST data from the server. And not delete/update any data.
- Obfuscate/encrypt the javascript files... just to make it a bit harder to de

And if the following is possible with Phonegap

- Add the android UID/Device ID to my database. So only whitelisted device can get access.

Should I use more security features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. HTTPS must be used for the life of the session. [OWASP A9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection)
2. The user-agent is an attacker controlled variable.  There is no
   point in checking this variable becuase it is trivial to spoof.
3. CRC is not a secure hash funciton.  It is triival to bypass this
   check my making a modification and then adding padding to create an
   identical CRC.  If a user modifes your app,  then can remove your
   bullshit CRC check.
4. The server **MUST** enforce access control,  assume an attacker can
   send you any request.
5. Do not rely upon (in)security though obscurity.
6. A user can send any request they would like,  so they can spoof this
   identifier.

An attacker does not have to modify your JavaScript in order to modify HTTP requests.  An attacker can use a BURP proxy or similar tool to intercept and modify requests before they reach your server.  Read the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project),  make sure your backend API is free from common defects.